# Change pacman mouth size in react-native

Tags: react-native

I am new to react-native. Currently learning the basics of creating shape in react-native. I would like to know how should I change the mouth size of the [pacman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UOMkL.png). Below is the code.

```
<View style={{
 width: 0,
 height: 0,
 borderTopWidth: 100,
 borderTopColor: 'red',
 borderLeftColor: 'red',
 borderLeftWidth: 100,
 borderRightColor: 'transparent',
 borderRightWidth: 100,
 borderBottomColor: 'red',
 borderBottomWidth: 100, 
 borderTopLeftRadius: 200,
 borderTopRightRadius: 200,
 borderBottomRightRadius: 200,
 borderBottomLeftRadius: 200
}}/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I figure out how it works. Basically I am working on some animation.